# Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'map' at line 3 column 0

Tags: trigger

```
trigger StudentIdnew on Account (Before Insert) { 

    map<Account,Account Number> map1=trigger.newmap;

    for(Account a : map1.values){

        if(a.AccountNumber == null){
            a.AccountNumber = '12345';

        }     

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Line `for(Account a : map1.values)` should be `for(Account a : map1.values())`

You could easily do `for(Account a : Trigger.new)` without creating another map.

Comment: Also line 3 does make full sense.  Should be: `map <id, Account> map1 = trigger.newmap;`

Comment: Good catch. Didn't notice that.